# I want to ensure either Name or PolicyNumber is supplied so I created below JSON schema. But it is accepting any values. Why?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to ensure either Name or PolicyNumber is supplied so I created below JSON schema. But it is accepting any values. Why?

---

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/Draft/2019-09/schema",
  "title": "Policy_Search_Input_v1.0",
    "PolicySearchInput": { 
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "PolicyNumber": {
                "type": "string"
            },  
            "MajorProductCode": {
                "type": "string",
                "description" : "Policy Type"
            },
            "AsOfDate": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
            },
            "FirstNamedInsured": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Party": {
                        "Name": { 
                        "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "PartyMailingAddress": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "City": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "StateCode": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "CountryCode": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "default": "US"
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }
            },
            "LineOfBusiness": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "RiskUnit" :{
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "Coverage": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "CoverageTriggerTypeCode": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "enum": [
                                            "O",
                                            "CM",
                                            "CMR"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },                                      
            "PolicyStatus": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "PolicyStatusCode": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "I",
                            "C"
                        ],
                        "description": "I(In Force), C(Cancellation)"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "anyOf": [
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties": {
                    "PolicyNumber": {
                        "required":["PolicyNumber"],
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                    }
                }   
            },
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties": {
                    "FirstNamedInsured": {
                        "Party": {
                            "Name": {
                                "required":["Name"],
                                "type": "string",
                                "minLength": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by putting your code in a formatted code block please? See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (expand the "Code and Preformatted Text" section).

Comment: _What_ is accepting any values? What validation/logic tool are you using to check input against the schema?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "properties" keyword above "PolicySearchInput" (line 3). The way you have it written, now, "PolicySearchInput" is being interpreted as a keyword, not a property name, so there is not actually any keyword present that would cause a failure.

You also have the same problem in the second clause of the "anyOf".

When you've fixed those issues, you should be able to see more clearly if there are any further problems.